# Framework for end to end testing flutter application

Tags: flutter, testing, automation, e2e

What is the most popular or most convenient framework to write automation tests (user flows) with flutter framework? any help advice would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Flutter provides its own out of the box solution for end-to-end testing. You can find documentation here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction.

Note that it says 'integration test' but it is what most people call an end to end test. Here is a table of Flutter terminology for test types vs the regular interpretation:

| Normal Test Name | Flutter Test Name |
| --- | --- |
| Unit Test | Unit Test |
| Integration Test | Widget Test |
| End-to-end Test | Integration Test |

Here is an overview of different test types in Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing

Answer (score 1):

Flutter does provide its own integration testing framework, but it's severely limited – for example, it doesn't let you interact with native permission request dialogs, test notifications, tap/enter text into WebViews.

That's why I recommend you try out [Patrol](https://patrol.leancode.co). It has extensive documentation that should get you up to speed quickly.

Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of Patrol, and Patrol isn't stable yet.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_convenient_test, which has the following features: "Write and debug tests easily, with full action history, time travel, screenshots, rapid re-execution, video records, interactivity, isolation and more."

Disclaimer: I created this package ;)

Comment: Inspired by cypress? This looks really good!